# TableLayoutPanel Controls.Add Problem

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I have a TableLayputPanel with 2 columns and 4 rows and I'm trying to add buttons to it at runtime.  I want to dynamically add each button to the first cell:

```
private int nextIndex = 1;

private void bAddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button newButton = new Button();
    newButton.Text = nextIndex.ToString();
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newButton, 0, 0);  // first cell
    nextIndex++;
}
```

As I understand it this should shifts all existing buttons up a cell. This seems to work the first three times but after that is inserts the new button into the 2nd cell a few times then the 3rd cell, then the 4th etc...

Is there a limit on how many times you can call Controls.Add(ctrl, column, row) for a given cell?

I bit stuck, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you only want the buttons to be added to the first cell?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I *do* see the same behavior. On a 3x3 panel I end up with 7, 6, 9, then 8, 5, 2 and 1, 4, 3. Even though the MS docs don't seem to mention shifting existing value, it does say the added control will be place at the given location. So at least I should end up with 9 in cell 0,0.

Comment: What's even weirder is how things change. After three clicks you have 3 2 1. The fourth button gets inserted after the 3 so you get 3 4 2 1. But on the fifth click, the 5 gets inserted after the 4 but also the 4 moves to the first position and 1 and 2 also switch positions! Very strange! So 321; 3421; 45312; 456123; 5674123. I don't see any logic in it.

Answer (score 3):

I've just had the same problem! What helped me was:

1. In design view of the form click your table
2. Set AutoScroll and AutoSize to True
3. Go to Edit Rows And Columns
4. Click The first (and probably only) row and set its Size Type to AutoSize

All new rows will also have Size Type AutoSize. Thanks to this my rows are located and resized properly.

Comment: I didn't have the OP issue but this solved my problem of auto resizing a DataGridView that I have inside a TableLayoutPanel when the Windows Form size gets dragged. Somehow when dragging the window borders the Datagridview won't auto resize and kept its static size. This really solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To add a number of buttons to a single cell you need to add a panel as the only control in the cell and then add your buttons to that panel.

Comment: Hi Matt,  Thank you for your quick response, sorry I probably wasn't clear enough, I only want one button per cell, but I want to add the new button to the fist cell making all existing buttons shift along by one cell.  My code does work the first three times but after that the same code insert into the wrong cell.

Comment: hmmm, I see what you mean it does do something quite strange doesn't it.